# Show/Hide partial view result one display at a time in foreach statement in main view at the click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partial list view inside a main view. The partial view is rendered in a foreach statement in the main view. I want to present the partial view result one display at a time, at the click of a button rather than displaying the list details on the page all at once, on a condition that a field in the currently displayed partial view is filled before allowing the next result to be displayed

In my main view:

```
<div class="">
   @foreach(var subline in Model.Lines)
   {
      @Html.Partial("_Lines", subline)
   }
 </div>
```

In my partial view:

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Lines"))
{
  <div class="partial-class-result">
     <div class="question-code">
        @switch (Model.Question_Code)
        {
            case "01":
                <h6>Question 1 of @ViewBag.NoOfQuestions</h6>
                break;
            case "02":
                <h6>Question 2 of @ViewBag.NoOfQuestions</h6>
                break;
            case "03":
                <h6>Question 3 of @ViewBag.NoOfQuestions</h6>
                break;
            case "04":
                <h6>Question 4 of @ViewBag.NoOfQuestions</h6>
                break;
            case "05":
                <h6>Question 5 of @ViewBag.NoOfQuestions</h6>
                break;
        }
    </div>
    <div class="question">
        <h5 class="arm-text-color">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Question)</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="response">
        <h5 class="arm-text-color">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Response)</h5>
    </div>
   
    <div class="survey-control">
        <button type="button" class="bg-info btn-group-lg btn-left">Previous</button>
        <button type="button" class="bg-info btn-group-lg btn-right">Next</button>
    </div>
   </div>
 }
```

My javascript code:

```
//next button
$('.btn-right').on('each', function (e) {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).parent().siblings('#Response').val() == '')
            return;
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $(this).parent().nextSibling().show();
    });
});
//previous button
$('.btn-left').on('each', function (e) {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $(this).parent().previousSibling().show();
    });
});
```

CSS code:

```
.partial-class-result {
   display: none;
}
```

My javascript code does not seem to do anything. I'd like to know how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get it to work.

Here's the modified Javascript code

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn-right', function (e) {
        var id = $(this).parent().parent().children().first().val();
        var resp = $('input[name="SurveyLines[' + id + '].Response"]:checked').val();
        if ($('input[name="SurveyLines[' + id + '].Response"]:checked').val() == undefined) {
            return;
        };
        if ($(this).parent().parent().next().is('div.survey-line')) {
            $(this).parent().parent().next().show();
            $(this).parent().parent().hide();

        } else {
            $('#submit-survey').parent().show();
        };
    });
```